# How to generate a subtotal in a bar chart (pgf tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, axis

I want to generate a bar chart like this one with subtotals (here in diamond shape):

[image]

I tried to work around a subtotal using a second axis, but the datapoints are not in the middle of the respective x coords.

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.7\textwidth,
            ybar stacked,
            bar width=20pt,
            enlargelimits=0.15,
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=0},
            ylabel={Values},
            symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E},
            xtick=data,
            ]
            \addplot+[fill=CornflowerBlue,  draw=black,ybar] plot coordinates {(A,25.959952)    (B,25.959952)   (C,98.703228) (D,64.219624) (E,64.219624)}; % 1
            \addplot+[fill=orange,          draw=black,ybar] plot coordinates {(A,10.383981)    (B,10.383981)   (C,39.481291) (D,25.687850) (E,25.687850)}; % 2
            \addplot+[fill=YellowGreen,     draw=black,ybar] plot coordinates {(A,9.085938) (B,9.085938)    (C,0)       (D,0)       (E,0)}; % 3
            \addplot+[fill=Periwinkle,      draw=black,ybar] plot coordinates {(A,3.634393) (B,3.634393)    (C,0)       (D,0)       (E,0)}; % 4
            \addplot+[fill=Goldenrod,       draw=black,ybar] plot coordinates {(A,6.467643) (B,6.467643)    (C,7.796889) (D,9.716245) (E,7.807715)}; % 5
            \legend{1,2,3,4,5}
            \addlegendimage{Lavender, mark=*, only marks, draw=black, mark size=2pt, yshift=-.5em}
            \addlegendentry{subtotals}
        \end{axis}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.7\textwidth,
            axis y line*=right,
            axis x line=none,
            axis y line=none,
            ymin=0, ymax=160,
            ytick=\empty,
            xtick=\empty,
            symbolic x coords={A,B,C,D,E},
            xtick=data
            ]
            \addplot [Lavender,mark=*, only marks, draw=black,mark size=2pt] plot coordinates {(A,49.064310)    (B,49.064310)   (C,138.184519)(D,89.907473) (E,89.907473)}; % subtotals
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]